# How to display test steps in Run window with Cucumber 6 in InteliJ?

Tags: java, cucumber

I'm trying to update from Cucumber 1.2 to 6.10 and I find that in the Run Window version 6 does not show each individual test step ( @When, @And @Then).
In version 1.2 each step is shown.

Is there an option that I have to explicitly set in version 6?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stepNotifications` option. But beware that conceptually this misrepresents steps as individual tests. JUnit and other tools that process JUnits outcome will be quite confused by this.

```java
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(stepNotifications = true)
public class RunCucumberTestWithStepNotifications {

}
```

- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/263
- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/577